# Kill function after click event JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I have a function that I want to be stopped when I run a 'close' click event.

The reasoning behind this is when I run `img.start` click event for the second time, the function is called again and is now running twice.

The function in question is a slideshow, so I really do need the function to only ever be running once on a page.

So just to be clear, when I click on `img.close`, I want the `BannerSlideshow` function to stop and not be running anymore.

**Start function click event**

```
$('img.start').click(function () {
  BannerSlideshow.Init()
});
```

**End function click event**

```
$('img.close').click(function () {
  //stop function BannerSlideshow from running
});
```

**Snippet of slideshow function**

```
var BannerSlideshow = (function () {
return {
    Init: function () {
        //slideshow functionality            
    }
```

*I have updated my question to be more specific, apologies guys.*

Answer (score 1):

you can do that by using bind () and unbind ()

```
$('img.close').bind('click',function () {
         // your code
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

OR

You can use Off()

```
$(this).off('click');
```

Comment: `$('img.close').bind` you missed the `.` in `.bind`

Comment: From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/): "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document." This isn't a new change, 1.7 was released months ago.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Though you are correct, it is more important to use `on()` instead of deprecated methods such as `live()` as they are gone in 1.9.1. `bind` hasn't been deprecated yet and is still a valid use at this point in time. Also, like all the other binding methods, it is using `on()` anyway behind the scenes.

Comment: @enterjq: I think [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) would work as well if you are unbinding anyway. `$('img.close').one('click',function () {...}); // unbinds itself after execution`

Comment: updated my question guys, thanks for the answers though so far. really appreciate that.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I'm aware it calls `.on()` behind the scenes, but that's really no excuse not to use the correct functions as far as I'm concerned. It's not inconceivable that `.bind()` will be removed at some point, the official documentation says you should use `.on()` instead, so you should write *new* code using it because it's likely to save you time later on.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: `bind` is still correct until deprecated. `on()` is **preferred** not a **must**. And no, `bind` will not be removed unless it is marked as deprecated first. Unless something is marked as deprecated you are still fine to use it, though as you **correctly** pointed out, it is recommended to follow the documentation :) Nontheless, it does not make the use of `bind()` at this time incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or use on.click

and kill using

```
$(this).off();
```

or

```
use .bind and  .unbind();
```

better see here :http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/

Answer (score 0):

you can use off method. [Off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

> (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to
>   attach and remove event handlers on elements

```
$('img.close').off('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use stop function with a boolean ?

```
var running = false;

$('img.close').click(function () {
    running = true;
```

});

if running = true, use stop() function otherwise start slide

I think stop function is better than to unbind handlers

Answer (score 0):

What does the StartSlideshow function look like? I guess you could have a global variable to run the slideshow or not...

```
function StartSlideshow() {
    globalVariableRunSlideshow = true;
    while (globalVariableRunSlideshow) {
         /* Do some slideshowing here */
    }
}
```

And then your event could do something like :

```
$('img.close').click(function () {
    globalVariableRunSlideshow = false;
});
```